# Type to unrelated type Protocol

Tags: swift, types, protocols

I have a protocol and a class that extends that protocol

```
public protocol P {
}

public class C: P {
}

print(C.self is P.Protocol)
```

Please why do I get `Cast from 'C.Type' to unrelated type 'P.Protocol' always fails` when printing?

Comment: Why do you even require that? Please explain the context.

Comment: If you want to check the types do `C.self is P.Type` but I m not sure I understand the purpose so I don't know if this is useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for **`is`** will work when you do it for an instance of type `C`, i.e.

```
let c = C()
print(c is P) //true
```